# how to Draw train route map between source and destination in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android draw route on a Mapview with twoo POI-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408671/android-draw-route-on-a-mapview-with-twoo-poi-s)

I draw route map between two areas using [Google direction API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/), but I am thinking to draw train route between two stations in android. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Here is a link from web.. Now I don't know how to get the kml file: http://www.google.com/maps?saddr=51.493480,+-0.168690&daddr=Streatham+High+Rd%2FA23&hl=en&ll=51.463098,-0.145569&spn=0.086735,0.222988&sll=51.474434,-0.144024&sspn=0.086713,0.222988&geocode=%3BFQrTEAMdTAv-_w&vpsrc=0&dirflg=rT&ttype=dep&date=12%2F14%2F11&time=7:00am&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=walk&mra=ls&t=m&z=13&start=0

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will be interested in Google TRANSIT and not google direction.

See [this](http://maps.google.com/m/directions?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=Granville%20Skytrain,%20Canada&daddr=ubc&mra=cc&dirflg=r&sll=49.27708,-123.18737&sspn=0.089594,0.202904&ie=UTF8&t=h) page and [this](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html) too.

Comment: There is no Google Transit API. The spreadsheet linked here isn't an official Google project, it's a spreadsheet with made up data, which it says on the spreadsheet. The feed specification is useful for getting data from agency providers, but you would have to get that route data from the transit agency specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide an official API for getting transit directions or to describe routes, you need to source the data from somewhere else.