# I dont want ItemizedOverlay to draw a image on every overlayitem it haver

Tags: android, path, maps

basically i am trying to draw the path i.e road path. for that i ususally have more then 50 geopoints to link together to draw a path, but the itemized over is also drawing the image on every point, The image that i passed in the constructor. Due to this apart from looking ugly it also slows down my phone. Ite even became hard to move the map too by touching the screen. 
so i dont want to draw any image on any geopoint, is it possible  or else i should go for Overlay, and a overlay for every couple of geopoint(two geopoints to draw a line between them). I think that would be a overhead for the mobile to manage too many overlays, i.e for 50 geopoints there would be 25 overlays on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just what ItemizedOverlay does. Sounds like you need a regular Overlay. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408671/android-draw-route-on-a-mapview-with-twoo-poi-s) an example.

Comment: I've used a regular overlay to draw path , and its working good, though ItemizedOverlay adds overheads to the performance !