# driving direction between current location to a given point

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android draw route on a Mapview with twoo POI-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408671/android-draw-route-on-a-mapview-with-twoo-poi-s)

I need to show / "draw" a route (driving direction) between current location to a given point,

how do i do it ?

example/method will be help full...

thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish we could down vote comments... This might help, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/4408990/1134705

Comment: @Asok: a vague question deserves a vague answer.

Comment: @RASG A vague question deserves questions for clarity or ignoring and moving on, a vague answer wastes space and time, much as we are doing now. You can't know something without learning it. I guess I take a more tolerant approach to beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685) is the answer. Just add the classes that is given there and call the required methods and it is done.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123) is a link to draw the direction between two points, you can put the first point as your location, and the second point your destination (depends on how you are going to fetch it from the user, there are various ways). As this is your first post, before you ask a question it is essential to search for similar questions and try by yourself.