# android direction on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm doing an app for directions on Google map. But when i run the app I have a problem `11-23 09:39:16.111: E/MapActivity(572): Couldn't get connection factory client` and it doesn't show/draw des and source on Map. Can you help me!

source code

**Main**:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
private MapView mapView;

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { return false; }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    //Example data
    double latitudeFrom = 50.06469036372934;
    double longitudeFrom = 19.944788217544556;
    double latitudeTo = 50.06400165088368;
    double longitudeTo = 19.920390844345093;

    GeoPoint srcGeoPoint = 
        new GeoPoint((int)(latitudeFrom * 1E6), (int)(longitudeFrom * 1E6));
    GeoPoint destGeoPoint = 
        new GeoPoint((int)(latitudeTo * 1E6), (int)(longitudeTo * 1E6));

    drawPath(srcGeoPoint, destGeoPoint, mapView);

    mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
}

private void drawPath(GeoPoint src, GeoPoint dest, MapView mapView) {
    String strUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en";
    //From
    strUrl += "saddr=" +
           (src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6) + 
           "," +
           (src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6);
    //To
    strUrl += "&daddr=" +
           (dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6) + 
           "," + 
           (dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6);
    //Walk attribute (for walk path)
    strUrl += "&dirflg=w";
    //File format
    strUrl += "&output=kml";

    try {
        //Parse KML
        URL url = new URL(strUrl.toString());

        SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();

        KMLHandler kmlHandler = new KMLHandler();
        reader.setContentHandler(kmlHandler);

        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        reader.parse(inputSource);

        String path = kmlHandler.getPathCoordinates();
        //Draw path
        if(path != null) {
            RouteOverlay routeOverlay = new RouteOverlay();

            String pairs[] = path.split(" ");

            for (String pair : pairs) {
                String coordinates[] = pair.split(",");
                GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]) * 1E6));
                routeOverlay.addGeoPoint(geoPoint);
            }

            mapView.getOverlays().add(routeOverlay);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("RoutePath", e.toString());
    }
    }
}
```

**KMLHandler**:

```
public class KMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private boolean inGeometryCollection = false;
private boolean inCoordinates = false;
private String pathCoordinates;

public String getPathCoordinates() { return pathCoordinates; }

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if(inGeometryCollection && inCoordinates)
        pathCoordinates = new String(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if(localName.equals("GeometryCollection")) inGeometryCollection = false;
    else if (localName.equals("coordinates")) inCoordinates = false;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if(localName.equals("GeometryCollection")) inGeometryCollection = true;
    else if (localName.equals("coordinates")) inCoordinates = true;
}
}
```

**RouteOverlay**:

```
public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay {
private ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints;
private int mRadius = 5;

public RouteOverlay() {
    geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
}

public void addGeoPoint(GeoPoint gp) {
    geoPoints.add(gp);  
}

@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
        long when) {
    if (shadow == false) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        GeoPoint geoPointFrom = null;
        GeoPoint geoPointTo = null;
        Point pointFrom = new Point();
        Point pointTo = new Point();

        //Route
        for (GeoPoint geoPoint : geoPoints) {
            if(geoPointFrom != null) {
                geoPointTo = geoPoint;

                projection.toPixels(geoPointFrom, pointFrom);
                projection.toPixels(geoPointTo, pointTo);

                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                paint.setAlpha(120);

                canvas.drawLine(pointFrom.x, pointFrom.y, 
                                pointTo.x, pointTo.y, 
                                paint);

                geoPointFrom = geoPointTo;
            } else {
                geoPointFrom = geoPoint;
            }
        }

        //Start point
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        projection.toPixels(geoPoints.get(0), pointFrom);
        RectF ovalStart = new RectF(pointFrom.x - mRadius, 
                                    pointFrom.y - mRadius,
                                    pointFrom.x + mRadius, 
                                    pointFrom.y + mRadius);
        canvas.drawOval(ovalStart, paint);

        //Stop point
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        RectF ovalStop = new RectF(pointTo.x - mRadius, 
                                   pointTo.y - mRadius,
                                   pointTo.x + mRadius, 
                                   pointTo.y + mRadius);
        canvas.drawOval(ovalStop, paint);
    }

    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}

}
```

Comment: Where is your ItemizedOverlay class per the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Comment: i only want show route from source to des on map, don't need show item.But with this code don't show.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need ItemizedOverlay as this is the way the MapActivity knows you have Overlay items. A route is an Overlay. See this SO question: [Android draw route on a Mapview with twoo POI-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408671/android-draw-route-on-a-mapview-with-twoo-poi-s)